# Disable keyboard shortcuts Alt + Tab in electron application on Window & MacOS

Tags: javascript, keyboard, electron

I am working with Desktop Application, while I am working on Ubuntu server, I can block keyboard shortcuts: **Alt+Tab** fine, but when I'm moved to window and try to block **Alt+Tab**, it's not working.

Here is the code that I am using currently:

```
const i = globalShortcut.register('Alt + Tab', () => {
    console.log('Alt&Tab is pressed')
})
```